# Free or inexpensive alternative to Dreamweaver

Tags: web-development, css, html-editor, templating

I've been using Dreamweaver for years however, the cost is killing me. Now that I hand code most of my work, the WYSIWYG feature is no longer interesting. There are two features I absolutely love about Dreamweaver:

1. The CSS editor - helps complete large CSS rules in a flash.
2. The Template feature - hands down the biggest time saver as my entire site is based off of one template.  All I need to do is make one change on my template and then my whole site gets updated.

I'm on the search for a free or less expensive solution. The only catch is I really want something that has a way to use templates similar to the way Dreamweaver uses them.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody had any suggestions, but I think I found something that fits my needs better.  [HTML-Kit Tools](http://www.htmlkit.com/tools/)  The template feature was a little confusing.  Support desk helped me figure out how to use templates just like dreamweaver [How To Use Templates](http://www.html-kit.com/forums/html-kit-tools/fluid-templates-how-to-use-2092/)  Hope this helps someone down the road!

Comment: If you need answers, try adding a bounty. You could also include more details like, what is your price range (especially max price), operating system.